# Automatically repeat the same arguments taken by a class constructor in a extern "C" function

Tags: c++, extern

It is possible to automatically *mirror/repeat* the arguments taken by `Test` constructor in the `create()` function, and pass them to the constructor, without using preprocessor macros?

Note 1: The `create()` function must be `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling - It will be a .so lib to be used in another C++ program by means of `dlopen()`/`dlsym()`. I've tried templates but it appears that it isn't accepted in `extern "C"` functions.

Note 2: The preferred solution will be the one with zero runtime overhead (If possible)

The idea is:

```cpp
class Test {
public:
    Test(/* some args */) {
    }
    /* other methods */
};

extern "C" Test* create(/* same args of Test class */) {
    return new Test(/* pass same args of this function */);
}
```

Comment: You can try C's variadic arguments ! man stdarg

Comment: @ChristopherJ. But it can automatically mirror arguments taken by `Test` constructor? If yes, how?

Comment: who drives the arguments: i.e. you start with `create` having a known signature and then you need to create `Test` to mirror it or the other way around: you start with a known signature for `Test::Test` and need to have `create` mirror it?

Comment: @bolov, I start with a known signature for `Test::Test` and need to have `create()` mirror it

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition you could create a params structure:

```
struct TestParams
{
    int x, y, z;
};

class Test {
public:
    Test(TestParams params) {
    }
    /* other methods */
};

extern "C" Test* create(TestParams params) {
    return new Test(params);
}
```

Or you could just bite the bullet and just copy-paste the parameters. In the end don't forget code is written once but read multiple times.